# Go application hangs in Docker

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a very simple go application that works fine under Windows and Mac. (I am a golang newbie btw). The purpose of the application is to subscribe to a google cloud pubsub subscription and forward the messages to another application using REST.

The code looks like:

```
func getOrCreateTopic() {
    log.Infof("1")
    ctx := context.Background()

    log.Infof("2")
    topicName := viper.GetString("gce.pubsub.topic")
    log.Infof("3")
    topic = client.Topic(topicName)
    log.Infof("4")
    exists, _ := topic.Exists(ctx)
    log.Infof("5")
    if topic == nil || !exists {
        topic, err = client.CreateTopic(ctx, topicName)
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorf("Failed to create topic %s: %v", topicName, err)
            os.Exit(2)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    ...
    getOrCreateTopic();
    ...
}
```

I created a docker container and published it to our kubernetes cluster in google cloud. What I see in the logs is everything until "4" and then nothing more. But the process is still shown as running in kubernetes.

I am lost, it seems like the call to the API just hangs.

Comment: Are you checking the error wherever you are creating the client?

Comment: Have you looked at a stack trace to see where it's actually hanging?

Comment: Are you checking the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env? https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform#step_5_configure_the_application_with_the_secret

Comment: Could you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: Solved it: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/issues/791

Comment: Do not add the word "Solved" to your title. Instead, provide an answer to your question, and accept it. With over 1k reputation, you should know this is how SO works.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is encountering this same issue, I was able to solve it using the link from the OP.  However, I looked past this link the first time I saw it because it mentioned using the cloud pubsub emulator.

I am not using the pubsub emulator in my project so I continued to read until I got to the section about SSL certificates.  The absence of SSL certificates was the root cause of the hanging function.

I am using the `scratch` docker image in my project which does not include ssl certificates by default.  I was able to resolve the hanging code by copying the ssl certificates from my golang build image in my multi-stage build.

```
FROM golang
COPY ./ /go/src/app
WORKDIR /go/src/app
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o /build/main

FROM scratch
COPY --from=0 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
COPY --from=0 /build/main /main
CMD ["/main"]
```

ps: I know this post is old, but I nearly missed the resolution so I wanted to help anyone else who might enounter this issue in the future.